# GPG Private Keys on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have the need for gpg encryption on my instance in Elastic Beanstalk.  What's the proper way to load my private keys on the machines?

I obviously do not want to store these files in the repository.  But they need to be on each instance for decryption.

How do I properly handle this?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [AWS Key Management Service](http://aws.amazon.com/kms/)